# Два listview на одном активити

Tags: android, java

Привет всем. Ситуация такая: мне нужно создать 2 списка (ListView) на одном активити и чтобы был общий скроллинг активити, а ListView по высоте занимали столько, сколько им надо (wrap_content). Но, помещять листвью внутрь скроллвью нельзя. Поэтому я вижу 2 варианта: 1. Динамически создавать список 2. Добавить первый листвью в header второго листвью. Соответственно второй листвью будет скроллиться одновременно с первым. Возможно ли это? Хотя если добавить первый листвью над вторым background будет общим, и все будет не так, как надо. Единственный вариант создавать список вручную?

Answer (score 1):

Представить не могу, зачем вам понадобилось именно два *ListView*, посему рискну предположить, что вы, скорее всего, просто хотите назначить два разных адаптера для *ListView*.

Посмотрите в сторону отличной библиотеки от небезызвестного Mark Murphy (aka commonsguy) — [CWAC MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) — она делает ровно то, что вы хотите. И делает это хорошо.

Небольшой пример использования всего этого дела:

```
MergeAdapter adapter = new MergeAdapter();
adapter.addAdapter(new YourFirstAdapter());
adapter.addAdapter(new YourSecondAdapter());
yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: ну а если мне хочется сделать 2а списка один под другим, например, в самом верху 10 контактов - избранных (список со своим адаптером), ниже - список - все контакты (другой кастом)?

Comment: Смотрите ответ выше.

    MergeAdapter adapter = new MergeAdapter();
    adapter.addAdapter(new FavoriteContactsAdapter());
    adapter.addAdapter(new AllContactsAdapter());
    yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);

И вы получите то, что хотите. Сперва элементы первого адаптера, затем — элементы второго адаптера. И всё это в одном ListView.

Comment: Нет. Листвью должны быть независимы друг от друга. В первом будут добавленные файлы в папку "Основные файлы", а во втором в "Прочие". Я так зациклен на листвью, потому что больше не знаю других компонентов, которые мне так подходят. Возможно есть аналог. Я реализовал это все дело не через листвью, а через layoutinflather. Вот так это выглядит сейчас: http://s019.radikal.ru/i608/1307/4c/3f5f57009fb9.jpg Но как отслеживать нажатие на итем пока не знаю.. Поэтому мне и нужен листвью. :)

Comment: вариант @falstaf подойдет, но можно сделать и вложеные лист-вью в леяуты, а их в скролл или как-то так

Comment: @Gorets: Нет, нельзя. Это не будет работать. Оба *ListView* в таком случае примут высоту, равную *?android:attr/preferredListItemHeight* (от 48 до 64 dp в стоковой реализации), куда у вас, в лучшем случае, поместится первый элемент списка.

Comment: @pulltofresh, признайтесь, вы ведь даже не ходили по ссылке, что я дал, не так ли? А если и ходили, то не удосужились не то, что саму библиотеку глянуть изнутри, так даже сэмпл, заботливо помещённый разработчиком в репозиторий, посмотреть. Да даже банально запустить его. В противном случае, все ваше споры прекратились бы. Но нет, вы предпочитаете впустую спорить, что-то мне пытаясь доказать, не попытавшись даже вникнуть, что вам, собственно, посоветовали. Не тем путём вы идёте, в общем.

Comment: @pulltofresh, и да, ваше решение (я так понимаю, там что-то типа *LinearLayout* + *LayoutInflater* + *layout.addView*) будет очень, очень плохо работать при большом количестве элементов вашего самодельного списка. Надеюсь, не нужно объяснять, почему?

Comment: большое спасибо. простите, что не сильно вчитался в Ваш пост.